# Keto-Enol tautomerism acidity of α Hydrogen vs stability of double bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, tautomer

If I consider a ketone that has an ethyl group and a methyl group attached to it. The α-Hydrogen of the methyl group would be more acidic than that of the ethyl group due to -I effect of the adjacent carbon in ethyl group. However the double bond formed in the enol form would be more stable in case it is formed using the α-carbon on ethyl since it's more substituted. In this case which enol form should I choose to be the more stable form ?

Comment: Stability of transition state depends upon the double bond formed. The more substituted enol should be major product here.

Comment: How does the question above answer my question? It compares between aldehyde and ketone but now doesn't talk about this

Comment: Look at the linked answers within the question linked..